# How can I include GCC headers in a Visual Studio program; are there any extra "gotcha" steps?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm a bit of a novice programmer - apologies if I'm missing anything obvious here.

Recently, I've wanted to play around with high-precision floats - specifically of the 128-bit quad-precision kind.

I found out that the GCC compiler has a `<quadmath.h>` header for this that can be `#include`'d in your code, but, well, I don't have the GCC downloaded and I'd much prefer to just use Visual Studio, which I already have set up.

Luckily, I found the [code for this GCC library on Github](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libquadmath), and it seems at first glance I can just download this and include them as source files. However, I'm a bit worried there's an extra step I'm missing, here - they are C files rather than C++, after all, and there are also a bunch of extra makefiles and such in the directory that might complicate this - and I don't necessarily know what to do.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you setting up Visual Studio to use the gcc compiler instead of the CL.EXE compiler?

Comment: @Eljay Nah, I'm not.

Comment: try it, see if it works. probably wont as it uses gcc's non standard float128 type

Comment: The library may or may not work. Hard to say. Folks developing library functions to support a particular compiler often write code [that some might consider... unnatural](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIHF8Xe-O6Y). It may use types and functions that only exist for that compiler and its library implementation or delve into [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) that they can get away with because they know exactly how the UB will behave with that specific compiler or on the processors targeted by that compiler.

Comment: I recommend you find a native solution. That code is literally part of the GCC toolchain. Maybe you can get it working but there be dragons. It's not like nobody else has put together high-precision float libs...

Answer (score 0):

The C files should work just fine. Just be sure to include .h at the end of the included file name. For example: `#include <stdio.h>` works just fine in C++.
However, your best bet would be to just install GCC as it would save you a lot of hassle in the future.